# Install dnspython on linux ubuntu

Tags: installation, dnspython

I have Ubuntu installed. I am trying to use zxlolbot. But when I open `zxlolbot.py` it gives me an error.

```
Please download dnspython
```

I tried to install dnspython but I couldn't install it. I don't use PuTTY.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the package `python-dnspython`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dnspython
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download dnspython from http://www.dnspython.org/.
2. Extract the contents.
3. Open the terminal and navigate to the extracted directory.
4. Type `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have (`pip` or `pip3`) installed.

Use one of these commands (depending on what your **pip version**):

```sh
pip install dnspython
pip3 install dnspython
```